# Minimum user rights need to run IIS 7.5 application pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We have an user (XXX\User). We want to run IIS 7.5 Application pool under this user.

I have configured application pool to run under this account, but whenever i am accessing application my app pool will crash with below error:

> Application pool ASP.NET v4.0123 has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not create a worker process to serve the application pool because the application pool identity is invalid
>
> Application pool ASP.NET v4.0123 has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool.
>
> The identity of application pool ASP.NET v4.0123 is invalid. The user name or password that is specified for the identity may be incorrect, or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not corrected, the application pool will be disabled when the application pool receives its first request.  If batch logon rights are causing the problem, the identity in the IIS configuration store must be changed after rights have been granted before Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity remains invalid after the first request for the application pool is processed, the application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the error number.

Please let us know what all permission we need to provide to this user in order to run application pool.

Note: Due to some constrain i cannot add this user in ***Administrators*** Group

Comment: Well, the most obvious first question is does the user have **Batch logon rights** and have you double-checked that you have provided correct username and password?

Comment: @Belogix: Thanks for quick reply. I have checked username and password and its correct. I can't assign Batch Logon right as my machine is in domain and that feature is disabled

Comment: Well that might be your issue then... I am not sure what else you can do other than user NetworkService or similar unless your domain guys setup user for you with similar permissions.

Comment: Have you looked at old questions on the subject? eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546435/user-rights-needed-for-iis-7-5-application-pool-user-domain-user-not-the-apppo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914653/how-to-use-domain-windows-user-account-as-app-pool-identity